# groovy execute intermittently returns no output nor error

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to use a Groovy script (to run with jenkins-cli.jar) to verify some git information.

To this end, I have the following simple groovy script:

```
def getBranchSha = { branch ->
  def wd = new File('/my/git/repo');
  def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer();
  def gitcmd = 'git show-ref ' + branch + ' --hash';
  def proc = gitcmd.execute(null, wd);
  proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr);
  proc.waitFor();

  def sha = sout.toString().trim();
  out.println("exitCode: " + proc.exitValue() + "\terror: " + serr.toString());
  out.println("input: " + branch + "\toutput: \"" + sha + "\"");
  assert sha.equals("10d94325c8fc1050f3e362d2fbb9f9041e6b9360");
}

getBranchSha("origin/master");
```

I expect this to construct a command line `git show-ref origin/master --hash` and execute that in the working dir of my git repo. I expect the output of this to be the current SHA of my origin/master branch in this repo `10d94325c8fc1050f3e362d2fbb9f9041e6b9360`, and the code asserts this to be the case.

Most of the time, this code runs exactly as expected, but sometimes for no reason I can see, the output is blank:

```
 > while [ $? -eq 0 ] ; do java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 groovy tst.groovy ; done
exitCode: 0     error:
input: origin/master    output: "10d94325c8fc1050f3e362d2fbb9f9041e6b9360"
exitCode: 0     error:
input: origin/master    output: "10d94325c8fc1050f3e362d2fbb9f9041e6b9360"

...

exitCode: 0     error:
input: origin/master    output: "10d94325c8fc1050f3e362d2fbb9f9041e6b9360"
exitCode: 0     error:
input: origin/master    output: ""
java.lang.SecurityException: Rejected: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.powerassert.PowerAssertionError
        at hudson.remoting.ClassFilter.check(ClassFilter.java:20)
        at hudson.remoting.MultiClassLoaderSerializer$Input.resolveClass(MultiClassLoaderSerializer.java:111)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:184)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:217)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:250)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.main(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.execute(CLI.java:338)
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:509)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:390)
```

Based on the zero exit code, I assume that the command has executed normally, but I don't understand why the output hasn't been received. I thought that it might be because I don't understand how `waitFor` is supposed to work, but I've tried placing the `proc.waitFor()` line at various points in the function with no difference.

Running a similar script to verify that `"pwd".execute().text.trim().equals("/")` seems to always return correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you get the same problem if you change your `new StringBuffer()` bits to `new StringWriter()`?

Comment: I just tried that, and it seems to do the same thing.

Comment: If you write a looping script to just directly run `git show-ref origin/master --hash` (without running the script), does it sometimes have missing output?

Comment: No. I had tried that, but neglected to mention so in the question. `while [ $(git show-ref master --hash) == "10d94325c8fc1050f3e362d2fbb9f9041e6b9360" ] ; do sleep 1 ; echo "kay" ; done` seems to run forever without any problem.

Comment: can you try `def gitcmd = ['/bin/bash', '-c', "git show-ref $branch --hash"]` to see if it's a shell issue?

Comment: Good idea, but exactly the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way that works. Rather than calling `waitFor` and `consumeProcessOutput` one after the other (in any order), the method `waitForProcessOutput` will reliably deliver the shell output to my groovy script.

```
def getBranchSha = { branch ->
  def wd = new File('/my/git/repo');
  def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer();
  def gitcmd = 'git show-ref ' + branch + ' --hash';
  def proc = gitcmd.execute(null, wd);
  proc.waitForProcessOutput(sout, serr);

  def sha = sout.toString().trim();
  out.println("exitCode: " + proc.exitValue() + "\terror: " + serr.toString());
  out.println("input: " + branch + "\toutput: \"" + sha + "\"");
  assert sha.equals("10d94325c8fc1050f3e362d2fbb9f9041e6b9360");
}

getBranchSha("origin/master");
```

This code will give me what I want. I don't understand why a combination of `waitFor` and `consumeProcessOutput` doesn't do the same thing though.

Comment: This works for me in Groovy `2.5.2`. I am using `mp3info` command on 500+ mp3 files and sometimes there was no output using `consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr) / waitFor()` After changing to `waitForProcessOutput(sout, serr)` it is working every time.